# Do I have to use comma before mathematical denotation?

Tags: commas

I am really confused with using comma.
Some authors use comma but some authors do not use it.
Let me introduce two sentences.

> 1. The power of the transmitter, P_t, is inversely proportional to the distance between the transmitter and the receiver, d(tx, rx).
> 2. The power of the transmitter P_t is inversely proportional to the distance between the transmitter and the receiver d(tx, rx).

Which one is correct?

Comment: Edited your question. Write wasn't right, and it's punctuation not grammar. As such it's a matter of style and your question will likely be removed. The choice is yours but to make it I would recommend thinking whether there is a pause there on reading, and why.

Comment: In the second sentence, is the formula italicised by any chance?

Comment: You need a comma in your specific case. If you don't have a comma, then P_t represents the transmitter and not the power.

Comment: As you say,  some authors will use a comma and some authors won't. It's a matter of style - neither is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the comma is usually used when the notation is being initially introduced and defined. It's an abbreviated form of:

> The power of the transmitter, which we will call P_t, is ....

The second form is used when the notation has already been defined, especially when it's a name for a specific instance of the phrase that precedes it.

> The power of the transmitter P_t<sub>1</sub> [as opposed to P_t<sub>2</sub>] is ...

If it's not being used as a specifier like this, we would generally not say both "power of the transmitter" and "P_t", since the denotation of the latter is already understood.